# Order comments by amount of points they got, Laravel 5.2 polymorphic relationship

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 3 tables Gallery, Comments and Votes, my votes table is polymorphic since votes can be added to either gallery or a comment, they look like this:

Comments:

```
id
user_id
gallery_id
content
```

Votes:

```
id
user_id
votable_type
votable_id
status
```

status can be either 'upvote' or 'downvote'. Each comment can be either upvoted or downvoted. Amount of points comments has is calculated from count('upvote') - count('downvote').
votable_type can either be 'App\Gallery' or 'App\Comment'

I want to get all the comments and order them by amount of points, comment with highest amount of points being at top.

How can I do this? so far I have this simple code but it does not do any counting of votes or ordering of comments by amount of points:

```
Comment::with('votes')->with('owner')
->where('gallery_id', $gallery->id)
->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, this does the trick:

```
    $comments = Comment::with('votes')->with('owner')
                                        ->where('gallery_id', $gallery->id)
                                        ->leftJoin('votes', 'votes.votable_id', '=', 'comments.id')
                                        ->selectRaw(
                                            'comments.*, count(case votes.status when "upvote" then 1 else null end) - count(case votes.status when "downvote" then 1 else null end) as points'
                                        )
                                        ->where('votes.votable_type','App\Comment')
                                        ->groupBy('comments.id')
                                        ->orderBy('points', 'desc')
                                        ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: This won't allow recent posts to get any visibility, for example [here's](https://medium.com/hacking-and-gonzo/how-reddit-ranking-algorithms-work-ef111e33d0d9#7314) how reddit does this kind of sorting

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sortBy` method on collections, and unfortunately, you cannot use standard pagination in that case:

```
Comment::with('votes')->with('owner')
->where('gallery_id', $gallery->id)
->sortBy(function($comment,$key){
    return $comment->votes->count();
});
```

This will return a collection with all the comments sorted by the number of votes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could accomplish this with the query builder using a join with grouping and ordering, but I believe the query would be rather difficult and not easy to digest half a year later when you're reviewing code.

A simpler option would be to create a method on the `Comment` model that returns the number of points, something along the lines of this:

```
public function getPointsAttribute()
{
    $points = 0;
    foreach ($this->votes AS $vote) {
        $points = $vote->status == 'upvote' ? $votes + 1 : $votes - 1;
    }
    return $points;
}
```

And then sort the collection of `Comments` after fetching them from the database:

```
Comment::where('gallery_id', $gallery->id)->get()->sortBy('points');
```

You can paginate the collection using `forPage()`, see the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-forpage).

Comment: Try using the `forPage()` method on the collection.

Comment: I would also consider simplifying the `Votes` model, maybe instead of the string `status` field use a signed integer `vote` field. Then it can have values -1 or 1.

Comment: I get an error calling getPointsAttribute: `ErrorException in Votable.php line 40: Undefined variable: votes.` Any idea why? my votes function looks like this: `public function votes(){
        return $this->morphMany(Vote::class, 'votable');
    }`

Comment: Don't know, looks good. Debug it like this: 'dd(Comment::find(1)->votes())' and see if you get a query builder instance.

Comment: if I add votes() with parenthesis then it works. I had to rewritte the getPointsAttribute like this: `$upvotes = $this->votes()->where('status', 'upvote')->count();
        $downvotes = $this->votes()->where('status', 'downvote')->count();
        $points = $upvotes - $downvotes;` It's strange that it doesn't work inside the class. In controller I did this `$comment = Comment::where('id',$request->comment)->first();` and then `dd($comment->votes);` not using parenthesis on votes this time and it worked, it gave me a list of all votes. but using $this->votes inside Votable class fails.

Comment: 'votes()' returns a query builder on which you can use where() and count(). 'votes' is basically equal to 'votes()->get', it returns a collecion.